# Try to get a cumulative sum out of columns which I sum on the fly

Tags: mysql, cumulative-sum

I have a following table -

```
+------------------------------------------+
¦ date       ¦ earn_points ¦ redeem_points ¦
¦------------+-------------+---------------¦
¦ 2015-05-05 ¦ 50          ¦ 30            ¦
¦------------+-------------+---------------¦
¦ 2015-05-05 ¦ 60          ¦ 30            ¦
¦------------+-------------+---------------¦
¦ 2015-05-04 ¦ 70          ¦ 50            ¦
¦------------+-------------+---------------¦
¦ 2015-05-04 ¦ 80          ¦ 40            ¦
¦------------+-------------+---------------¦
¦ 2015-05-03 ¦ 30          ¦ 20            ¦
+------------------------------------------+
```

I'm looking for the following result -

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦ date       ¦ total_earn_points ¦ total_redeem_points ¦ total_liability_points ¦ Cumulative_liability_points ¦
¦------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------¦
¦ 2015-05-05 ¦ 110               ¦ 60                  ¦ 50                     ¦ 120                         ¦
¦------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------¦
¦ 2015-05-04 ¦ 150               ¦ 90                  ¦ 60                     ¦ 70                          ¦
¦------------+-------------------+---------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------¦
¦ 2015-05-03 ¦ 30                ¦ 20                  ¦ 10                     ¦ 10                          ¦
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I'm trying this SQL query but couldn't get the correct cumulative total:

```
SELECT `transaction_date`, 
IFNULL(SUM(rewards_point_rewarded),0) AS `total_earn_points`, 
IFNULL(SUM(rewards_point_redemed),0) AS `total_redeem_points`, 
(SUM(rewards_point_rewarded) - SUM(rewards_point_redemed)) AS `total_liability_points`, 
@total := @total + (SUM(rewards_point_rewarded) - SUM(rewards_point_redemed)) AS `Cumulative_liability_points` 
FROM `i_report_total_order`, (SELECT @total:=0) AS t 
WHERE (website_id = '36') 
GROUP BY `transaction_date` 
ORDER BY `transaction_date` DESC
```

Please help to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore Alexandre's comment, you've obviously had a go, structured a solid qu and people can always choose not to answer.

It's actually a bit of a minefield doing cumulatives using @ variables across groups in MySQL.

I'd take the approach of getting the non-cumulatives first and then using the @ variables to find the solution:

```
  SELECT date, 
         SUM(earn_points) AS tot_earn_pts, 
         SUM(redeem_points) AS tot_redeem_pts
    FROM i_report_total_order
/* WHERE website_id = 36 */
GROUP BY date 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Then:

```
  SELECT date,
         tot_earn_pts,
         tot_redeem_pts,
         tot_earn_pts - tot_redeem_pts AS tot_liability_pts,
         @cum := @cum + tot_earn_pts - tot_redeem_pts AS cum_liability_pts
    FROM (   
      SELECT date, 
             SUM(earn_points) AS tot_earn_pts, 
             SUM(redeem_points) AS tot_redeem_pts
        FROM i_report_total_order
     /* WHERE website_id = 36 */
    GROUP BY date 
         ) tots
    JOIN (SELECT @cum := 0) init
ORDER BY date
```

Unfortuately, you'll have to wrap this again to get the date order you specified.. but you can avoid the `IFNULLS` by setting the columns to `NOT NULL`

See [SQLFiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9d6b/5)

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT date,
           tot_earn_pts,
           tot_redeem_pts,
           tot_earn_pts - tot_redeem_pts AS tot_liability_pts,
           @cum := @cum + tot_earn_pts - tot_redeem_pts AS cum_liability_pts
      FROM (   
        SELECT date, 
               SUM(earn_points) AS tot_earn_pts, 
               SUM(redeem_points) AS tot_redeem_pts
          FROM i_report_total_order
       /* WHERE website_id = 36 */
      GROUP BY date 
           ) tots
      JOIN (SELECT @cum := 0) init
  ORDER BY date  
       ) res_asc
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Updated [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a9d6b/11)

Comment: I check the fiddle you created. If I change the date order by DESC the result show incorrect. The latest date value should be larger than earlier dates.

Comment: 'Unfortuately, you'll have to wrap this again to get the date order you specified..', the user variables get evaluated in the order specified by the query.. if you are summing them then the last row will be the largest.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your help this is the query worked in my case

```
SELECT `transaction_date`, 
       `total_earn_points`, 
       `total_redeem_points`, 
       `total_liability_points`, 
       @total := @total + `total_liability_points` AS `Cumulative_liability_points` 
       FROM (
              SELECT `transaction_date`, 
              SUM(rewards_point_rewarded) AS `total_earn_points`, 
              SUM(rewards_point_redemed) AS `total_redeem_points`,
              (SUM(rewards_point_rewarded) - SUM(rewards_point_redemed)) AS `total_liability_points`  
              FROM `i_report_total_order` 
              WHERE (website_id = '36') 
              GROUP BY `transaction_date` 
              ORDER BY `transaction_date` ASC
       ) tots 
join (SELECT @total:=0) AS init 
ORDER BY `transaction_date` ASC
```

it work only if I set ASC in last line. Is there a way to show latest date on top.